# Want to plot different sized/colored ellipses on matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a plot with an assortment of differently sized/colored ellipses and want to create a "general" legend for them, e.g. "big red ellipse means this, small blue ellipse means that" etc.

I have followed the HandlerPatch example here, which gets me 75% of the way there. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html

Using the example above I can get ellipse shapes in the legend, and i can customize each ellipse's color (by giving each mpatches.Circle object a color argument). That's 75% of it... but they are all the same height/width and I don't know how I can control that because there is no width argument for the mpatches.Circle object, and the height/width is "hard coded" into the create_artists function for the HandlerEllipse class. I'm probably very close but am completely stuck! Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT** GOT IT!

So what I did, thanks to Thomas Lang's suggestion to look at this link (https://intoli.com/blog/resizing-matplotlib-legend-markers/), was to do something similar. Plot the ellipses on the legend and then loop through them and alter their attributes. See code below:

'''python

```
#exact same class as matplotlib example:
class HandlerEllipse(HandlerPatch):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        center = 0.5 * width - 0.5 * xdescent, 0.5 * height - 0.5 * ydescent
        p = mpatches.Ellipse(xy=center, width=width + xdescent,
                             height=height + ydescent)
        self.update_prop(p, orig_handle, legend)
        p.set_transform(trans)
        return [p]

cmap = cm.get_cmap(name='Spectral_r', lut=None)
#plotting a test case "two entry legend", tring to get two differently sized, differently colored ellipses    
c = [mpatches.Circle((),color=cmap(0.1))
     ,mpatches.Circle((),color=cmap(0.9))]
legend = axs[plot].legend(c,['Small Blue','Big Red'], handler_map={mpatches.Circle: HandlerEllipse()})
#here's the 'trick', loop through each legend handle and alter their widths.. using the enumerate function to move along sequentially
for i,legend_handle in enumerate(legend.legendHandles):
    legend_handle.width = (10+i*10)
```

'''

Comment: Please state what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried putting a width argument into the mpatches.Circle object - this doesn't work because circle object has no width argument, and changing the radius argument doesn't do anything because it all gets overridden by the handler_map anyway (which transforms it into an ellipse). So from there I played with the create_artists function in the HandlerEllipse class.. and found I can hard code in a width there and it will alter the size of the ellipses plotted in the legend... but they are all the same size and I don't know how to pass variable sizes into the HandlerEllipse class...

Comment: I also tried just adding mpatches.Ellipse objects to the legend, but it displays them as rectangle patches (as expected).

Comment: Hm, maybe check out [this](https://intoli.com/blog/resizing-matplotlib-legend-markers/) link, under there there is some `legend_handle._legmarker.set_markersize(9)`.

Comment: Just tried it, thanks for link. Unfortunately got  "Ellipse object has no attribute '_legmarker'" . But that opens up a new idea for a solution, maybe I can alter the width/height of the ellipse objects by changing an attribute in a loop just like your link does for marker objects....

Comment: If you want to show the code you currently have for creating the two ellipses with their legend entries, I'd be happy to show you how to change it.

Comment: This works: for i,legend_handle in enumerate(legend.legendHandles):
        legend_handle.width = (i*(some multiplier)+(some base width)

Comment: I got it now, wow thanks so, so much for pointing me down that road. amazing.

Answer (score 1):

You can take over the size from the proxy artist you create and pass it into the legend handler.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerPatch
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

class HandlerEllipse(HandlerPatch):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        center = 0.5 * width - 0.5 * xdescent, 0.5 * height - 0.5 * ydescent
        p = mpatches.Ellipse(xy=center, width=orig_handle.width,
                                        height=orig_handle.height)
        self.update_prop(p, orig_handle, legend)
        p.set_transform(trans)
        return [p]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap(name='Spectral_r', lut=None)

c = [mpatches.Ellipse((), width=10, height=5, color=cmap(0.1)),
     mpatches.Ellipse((), width=20, height=5, color=cmap(0.9))]
legend = ax.legend(c,['Small Blue','Big Red'], handler_map={mpatches.Ellipse: HandlerEllipse()})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: OOHHH ok, I think I understand that handle_map better now. Thanks for this. My example in my edit gives me the same result but this is way cleaner.

Comment: But this just begs the question, why on god's green earth did the matplotlib example involve passing a circle object to the ellipse handler? Why not pass an ellipse object to the ellipse handler in the example?!

Comment: It's probably to keep the code shorter. An ellipse requires to set its width and height. But a circle doesn't. So this is to show that you just need to pass an object from which `update_prop` would work.